# Strange exception after IChangeFeedObserver ProcessChangesAsync

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create replication from CosmosDB to local CouchBase Lite database. For this I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor

But for some reason always after IChangeFeedObserver ProcessChangesAsync has ended I get following exception on console:

What does "Errors":["One of the specified pre-condition is not met"] mean? Replication is ended succesfully otherwise but this bothers me.

**Updated** with system.diagnostics

```
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 53 : 09/25/2017 08:27:54: Host 'TESTIkiosk' starting to check for available leases.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 54 : 09/25/2017 08:27:54: Host 'TESTIkiosk' starting to check for available leases.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 55 : 09/25/2017 08:27:54: Host 'TESTIkiosk' 1 partitions, 1 hosts, 0 available leases, target = 1, min = 0, max = 0, mine = 1, will try to take 0 lease(s) for myself'.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 56 : 09/25/2017 08:27:54: Host 'TESTIkiosk' 1 partitions, 1 hosts, 0 available leases, target = 1, min = 0, max = 0, mine = 1, will try to take 0 lease(s) for myself'.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 57 : 09/25/2017 08:28:06: Host 'TESTIkiosk' starting renewal of Leases.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 58 : 09/25/2017 08:28:06: Host 'TESTIkiosk' renewing lease for PartitionId '0' with lease token '"0000fa04-0000-0000-0000-59c893d40000"'
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 59 : 09/25/2017 08:28:06: Host 'TESTIkiosk' starting renewal of Leases.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 60 : 09/25/2017 08:28:06: Host 'TESTIkiosk' renewing lease for PartitionId '0' with lease token '"0000fb04-0000-0000-0000-59c893d40000"'
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 61 : 09/25/2017 08:28:06: Host 'TESTIkiosk' attempted to renew lease for PartitionId '0' and lease token '"0000fa04-0000-0000-0000-59c893d40000"' with result: 'True'
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 62 : 09/25/2017 08:28:06: Host 'TESTIkiosk' attempted to renew lease for PartitionId '0' and lease token '"0000fb04-0000-0000-0000-59c893d40000"' with result: 'True'
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 63 : 09/25/2017 08:28:07: Host 'TESTIkiosk' starting to check for available leases.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 64 : 09/25/2017 08:28:07: Host 'TESTIkiosk' starting to check for available leases.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 65 : 09/25/2017 08:28:07: Host 'TESTIkiosk' 1 partitions, 1 hosts, 0 available leases, target = 1, min = 0, max = 0, mine = 1, will try to take 0 lease(s) for myself'.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 66 : 09/25/2017 08:28:07: Host 'TESTIkiosk' 1 partitions, 1 hosts, 0 available leases, target = 1, min = 0, max = 0, mine = 1, will try to take 0 lease(s) for myself'.
[08:28:15 INF] Change feed in Ingredients: total 1 doc(s)
[08:28:15 INF] Replicated 2614
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 67 : 09/25/2017 08:28:15: Partition '0' update failed because the lease with token '"0000e804-0000-0000-0000-59c893b20000"' was updated by same/this host with token '"00000005-0000-0000-0000-59c893e50000"'. Will retry, 4 retry(s) left.
ChangeFeedEventHost Information: 68 : 09/25/2017 08:28:15: Checkpoint: partition 0, new continuation '"81"'


DocDBTrace Error: 0 : DocumentClientException with status code PreconditionFailed, message: Message: {"Errors":["One of the specified pre-condition is not met"]}, inner exception: null, and response headers: {
"x-ms-last-state-change-utc": "Sun, 24 Sep 2017 21:03:48.392 GMT",
"lsn": "954",
"x-ms-schemaversion": "1.3",
"x-ms-quorum-acked-lsn": "954",
"x-ms-current-write-quorum": "3",
"x-ms-current-replica-set-size": "4",
"x-ms-documentdb-partitionkeyrangeid": "0",
"x-ms-xp-role": "1",
"x-ms-request-charge": "1.24",
"x-ms-serviceversion": " version=1.17.52.1",
"x-ms-activity-id": "b9877abb-6203-4408-b1c3-92c9f52aad67",
}
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : Operation will NOT be retried. Current attempt 0, Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PreconditionFailedException: Message: {"Errors":["One of the specified pre-condition is not met"]}
ActivityId: b9877abb-6203-4408-b1c3-92c9f52aad67, Request URI: /apps/c9c8f510-0ca7-4702-aa6c-9c596d797367/services/75cca430-a307-47a0-89aa-82aabf32e065/partitions/53fb63ca-95ae-4d13-90be-d32f1a88843c/replicas/131504697049132845p/
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportClient.ThrowIfFailed(String resourceAddress, StoreResponse storeResponse, Uri physicalAddress, Guid activityId)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RntbdTransportClient.<InvokeStoreAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<WriteAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<InvokeAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<<InvokeAsync>b__0>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<<ExecuteAsync>b__d>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<InvokeAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreClient.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<UpdateAsync>d__305.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ReplaceDocumentPrivateAsync>d__13d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ReplaceDocumentPrivateAsync>d__135.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()
```

Code for my Implementation:

```
    using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Solteq.Pos.Repositories.Feeds
    {
        internal class MyHostFeed : IChangeFeedObserver
        {
            private int s_totalDocs = 0;
            private Func<dynamic, bool> replicate;
            private string name;

            public Func<dynamic, bool> Replicate { get => replicate; set => replicate = value; }
            public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }

            public Task OpenAsync(ChangeFeedObserverContext context)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker opened for {0}, {1}", name, context.PartitionKeyRangeId);
                return Task.CompletedTask;  // Requires targeting .NET 4.6+.
            }
            public Task CloseAsync(ChangeFeedObserverContext context, ChangeFeedObserverCloseReason reason)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker closed for  {0}, {1}", name, context.PartitionKeyRangeId);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            public Task ProcessChangesAsync(ChangeFeedObserverContext context, IReadOnlyList<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document> docs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Change feed in {0}: total {1} doc(s)", name, Interlocked.Add(ref s_totalDocs, docs.Count));
                foreach (var one in docs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Replicated: " + one.Id);
                    Replicate(one);
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
    }
```

And initialization of Observer:

```
        public async void StartReplication(string replicateFrom, string hostName, Func<dynamic, bool> replicate)
        {

            // Customizable change feed option and host options 
            ChangeFeedOptions feedOptions = new ChangeFeedOptions();

            // ie customize StartFromBeginning so change feed reads from beginning
            // can customize MaxItemCount, PartitonKeyRangeId, RequestContinuation, SessionToken and StartFromBeginning
            // feedOptions.StartFromBeginning = true;

            ChangeFeedHostOptions feedHostOptions = new ChangeFeedHostOptions();

            // ie. customizing lease renewal interval to 15 seconds
            // can customize LeaseRenewInterval, LeaseAcquireInterval, LeaseExpirationInterval, FeedPollDelay 
            //feedHostOptions.LeaseRenewInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            feedHostOptions.LeasePrefix = replicateFrom;
            feedHostOptions.FeedPollDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

            try
            {
                DocumentCollectionInfo documentCollectionLocation = new DocumentCollectionInfo
                {
                    Uri = new Uri(_databaseServiceUri),
                    MasterKey = _databaseAuthKey,
                    DatabaseName = _databaseId,
                    CollectionName = replicateFrom
                };
                DocumentCollectionInfo leaseCollectionLocation = new DocumentCollectionInfo
                {
                    Uri = new Uri(_databaseServiceUri),
                    MasterKey = _databaseAuthKey,
                    DatabaseName = _databaseId,
                    CollectionName = "leases"
                };
                DocumentFeedObserverFactory docObserverFactory = new DocumentFeedObserverFactory(replicate, replicateFrom);
                ChangeFeedEventHost host = new ChangeFeedEventHost(hostName, documentCollectionLocation, leaseCollectionLocation, feedOptions, feedHostOptions);

                await host.RegisterObserverFactoryAsync(docObserverFactory);
                hosts.Add(host);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Replication process halted for (" + replicateFrom + ") reason: " + e.ToString());
                //throw e;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this exception being thrown in the ProcessChangesAsync function or are you just seeing it in console during the Change Feed Processor's lifetime?

Comment: Is this stack trace full? It doesn't show up which operation caused it. Does this repro consistently? Can you enable tracing, get a repro and share trace log?

Comment: You can enable tracing like this:
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="ChangeFeedEventHost" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" switchValue="Verbose"> <!-- All, Verbose, Warning, Information, Error, Off -->
        <listeners>
          <clear />
          <add name="console" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true">
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

Comment: Yes that is full stack trace and this happens always. Added this system.diagnostics and updated post.

There seems to be something related on rival leases. I have two ChangeFeeds, one for each collection I'm monitoring.

Comment: @duumiska -- Did you ever figure this out? I get it every time just like you.

Comment: @Andy nope, this still happens every time, replication still works anyway. Just annoying exceptions...

Answer (score 4):

This is part of the Tracing, not an error, it’s viewable in Visual Studio because tracing is on.

When the ProcessChangesAsync finishes, the Processor updates the lease. But there is a separate thread that also maintains leases updated. It’s natural that there is a chance that both threads try to write the same document and generate a concurrency exception (the Pre-condition message), so the Processor traces it and retries and moves on.

This is not an unexpected error, it’s a handled and expected one, the Library just makes sure to trace all the situations.

Comment: >the Library just makes sure to trace all the situations.
+1 but alternate view:  'the library has some confusing/incorrect logging, but the V2 CFP impl is only receiving minimal maintenance effort atm as the Cosmos V3 SDK includes a fork of it" - if the V3 lib still does this (I dont know because [I'm waiting for CheckpointAsync to be reinstated](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/616)), it should be considered a bug for it to log about normal things at Info level

Comment: related: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet/issues/43